# ffmpeg conversion - vp8 with alpha

Tags: ffmpeg, transcoding

I'm trying to convert a mov file (with alpha channel) to webm, vp8 with alpha, on windows.

`ffmpeg -i C0016.mov -s 960x540 -vcodec vp8 -pix_fmt yuva420p -metadata:s:v:0 alpha_mode="1" c0016_alpha.webm​`

gives me:

[NULL @ 00000204af221e80] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'c0016_alpha.webm​'
c0016_alpha.webm​: Invalid argument

How can I fix it?

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: May i know the reason of using the option -pix_fmt yuva420p ?

Answer (score 0):

I took the sample from apple https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/506/

My command line using on colab was

```
!ffmpeg -y -i https://devstreaming-cdn.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2019/506lqy7sprpfyo800/506/506_hd_hevc_video_with_alpha.mp4 -s 960x540 -vcodec vp8 -metadata:s:v:0 alpha_mode="1" c0016_alpha.webm
```

Hope it matches your scenario.